# iOS Swift 3 how to perform an action after animation is done

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, swift3, uikit

I use the following code to make sure when the user opens the keyboard, it opens slowly and pushes the view up.

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification){
    tableViewChat?.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    let info2 = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info2[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
    })
}
```

Until here everything is working like a charm. Now i want to execute this line after the animation is done.

```
self.tableViewChat?.scrollToLastRow(animationBool: true)
```

If the animation is not fully executed, the tableview wont scroll down enough. How can perform the  scrollToLastRow after the animate is executed?

Thank you for your help and comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the completion block of the animation.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
 },completion{
    self.tableViewChat?.scrollToLastRow(animationBool: true)
})
```

This won't scroll the tableview until the animation is finished. In this case, 4 seconds.